# Type casting character in to integer

Tags: c, casting

I would like to know one thing about type casting where as far as I know the variable can be cast to other types on certain operations.

```
int c;
char i;
i = (char)c;
```

Type casts `c` as character and assigns to `i`. Where as `c= (int)i;` Type casts `i` as integer.

Is there any difference  between the two operations mentioned above? What happens when a character is assigned as integer using type cast?

Comment: You're asking the right questions!
The only difference between char and int is the number of bits. char is 8 bits, and int is usually 32 or sometimes 64.

Look up "sign extension" and you'll be on target.

Comment: in fact there's no need to cast in these cases. Types smaller than int are implicitly cast to int and int will be truncated when assigned to smaller types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the *char* is actually a tiny signed integer having 8 bits, *int* having usually 16 or 32 bits is also a signed integer.

Doing

```
char c = X;
int i = (int)c;
```

copies the 8 bits of *c* into *i* and expands the sign of *c*. I.e. -10 in *c* would set -10 in *i*.

But doing

```
int i = X;
char c = (char) i;
```

will copy only the 8 least significant bits of *i* into *c*. The remaining bits of *i* are lost (using `gcc -Wall` gives a warning).

Comment: Thank you @ring0.But i have a doubt. What will happen if i is -10 and casting in to 'unsigned int'?

Comment: If `i == 10` copying *i* into *c* will copy `10`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types . A signed char value is from -128 to +127.

Comment: I asked about '-10' @ringo. Sorry i did not made it understandable for you.If the character is negative 10 then converting to unsigned int will result in what value?.

Comment: Potentially nitpicky, but technically it is implementation-defined whether a plain `char` is signed or unsigned, and while `char` must be at least 8 bits, it's allowed to be more (and would have to be, if every member of the basic execution character set could not be represented in an 8 bit number).

Comment: @Paul agreed, and thank you for the precision - in my opinion that would be complicating the issue for a C beginner, especially on nowadays machines.

Comment: @Rookie91 [This page](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/08/a-tutorial-on-signed-and-unsigned-integers/) has many exemples, also comments are interesting.

Comment: `char` may be signed or unsigned. Many compilers have an option to toggle this, and implementations where it defaults to `unsigned` are common today

Answer (score 5):

Basically when you type cast from higher type to lower type  truncation happens. i.e Loss of data happens

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

 char c;
 int i=2000; 
 c=(char)i;
 printf("%d",c);
}
```

Bit representation for i=2000

---> (MSB)`0000011111010000`(LSB)

So Here char is 8 bit when you typecast int to char only 8 bit from lsb get stored remaining bits are truncated.
i.e -->  `11010000` typically this value get stored in `c`

take two complements of above one to get value.

--->`00110000`  i.e 48 and `MSB` bit is `1` since its signed char so the final value is

---> `-48`

```
 include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {

  char c=200;
  int i;
  i=(int)c;
  printf("%d",i);
 }
```

Bit representation for c=200 is `11001000`

So Here int  is 32 bit  when you typecast  char to int the  MSB bit get extended .Its a machine dependent implementation. If MSB is 1 then sign extension happens if 0 zero is filled in rest of bits

From K&R

There is one subtle point about the conversion of characters to integers. The language does
not specify whether variables of type char are signed or unsigned quantities. When a char is
converted to an int , can it ever produce a negative integer? The answer varies from machine
to machine, reflecting differences in architecture. On some machines a char whose leftmost
bit is 1 will be converted to a negative integer (``sign extension'
'
). On others, a char is
promoted to an int by adding zeros at the left end, and thus is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference whether you write a cast or not, in this situation. The issue is *conversion* of a `char` to an `int`. In C, there is *implicit conversion* between these two types: you can just assign one to the other without a cast, and a conversion happens. A cast is an *explicit conversion*. In other words, `i = c;` and `i = (char)c;` are exactly the same.

To understand the conversion, it seems easier to me to think in terms of *values*, rather than representations, sign extension, etc. etc.

When you write `i = c;`, it means that the value of `i` should be the same as the value of `c`.  If `c` was `-4` then `i` will also be `-4`, regardless of which bits are set in memory to represent this.

This always works, because all possible `char` values are also valid `int` values.

However when you go `c = i;` you may find that `i` has a value that is not a valid `char`. For example if your compiler gives `char` a range of `[-128, 127]` (this is common, but not the only possibility), and `i` had a value of `150`, then it is out of range.

When you assign an out-of-range value , what happens depends on whether the target type is signed or not.

- If your `char`s are `unsigned`, then the value is adjusted modulo `CHAR_MAX+1` until it is in range
- If your `char`s are `signed` then the behaviour is *implementation-defined*.

The latter means that the compiler must document what happens. It is also permitted to raise a signal (similar to a segfault occurring, if you're not familiar with signals).

On typical systems, the compiler will take the lower 8 bits of 2's complement representation, but this is certainly not something you should rely on; in order to write robust code, you should avoid triggering this operation.

You can inspect the ranges for your types by doing `#include <limits.h>`, and looking at `CHAR_MIN`, `CHAR_MAX`. (Those can be output via `printf("%d, CHAR_MIN);` etc.)